# Odd behavior of my jQuery shorthand "$.get()" ajax method and its callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resendActivationEmailLink").bind("click", function(event) {
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function() {
            $("#emailNotActivated").html("<span>not yet activated. email sent!</span>");
        });
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Although the ajax call does work, the callback function of the get() function is not called i.e. this line is not called:

```
$("#emailNotActivated").html("<span>not yet activated. email sent!</span>");
```

Can anyone please help?

**EDIT**:
Request object from ajaxError:

```
Object {readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseText: "dummy"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
```

EDIT 2:
Output from: `console.log($(this).attr('href'));`

```
/bignibou/resendActivationEmail/235617cb-c19c-4694-ab9e-753e5d7QQde07
```

Comment: Is there a js error on the page?

Comment: No. Nothing in the console...

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `return false`? It's an asynchronous call so it's probably being executed prior to the return of your AJAX call.

Comment: I have just tried commenting out "return false". To no avail...

Comment: What does `console.log($(this).attr("href"))` print?  Is that URL on the *same domain* as your page?

Comment: Yes because the controller method does get invoked.

Comment: please post the value of `console.log($(this).attr('href');` and as long as `return false` does the same as `event.preventDefault()` you can choose only one. there is no need for them both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up an [error handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
    alert( "Error requesting page " + settings.url);
});
```

Does this get triggered? Look at what is returned in the Ajax call in the console.

- EDIT -

So the error response shows 4 and 200, so that is fine. The next issue could be parsing. Try to set the data type so jQuery does not guess and fail.

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"), function(){ ... }, "html")
```

If that works, I am betting your serverside code is returning back the wrong content type with the response.

Comment: Good tip: it does get triggered! I can't pinpoint the exact error though.

Comment: Does setting the datatype make a difference? `$.get($(this).attr("href"), function(){ ... }, "html");`

Comment: Yes epascarello: it does work now with the datatype... Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
  if(data){
    $("#emailNotActivated").html("<span>not yet activated. email sent!</span>");
  }
});
```